# why code ->setIsMassupdate(true) is used?

Tags: admin, grid

I used below function in admin controller to update multiple store status. Its working fine. 
why code  ->setIsMassupdate(true) is used?  What it does?

```
public function massStatusAction()
{
    //Get store ids from selected checkbox
    $storeIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('storeIds');

    if (!is_array($storeIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select store(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
                Mage::getSingleton('clarion_storelocator/storelocator')
                ->load($storeId)
                ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))
                **->setIsMassupdate(true)**
                ->save();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($storeIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess in your own entity it doesn't make sense.
But for products is useful.
If you have some indexes set on 'Update on save' and you perform a mass update, there is no need to rebuild those indexes for each product that is updated in bulk. You can just rebuild the indexes when everything product is updated.

For example this piece of code from `Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Observer::processAfterSaveEvent` uses that flag.

```
    if (!$eventProduct->getIsMassupdate()) {
        $this->_getIndexer()->plainReindex($eventProduct);
    } else {
        $this->_productIdsMassupdate[] = $eventProduct->getId();
    }
```

If the `getIsMassupdate` returns `false`, then it reindexes the product, If it's `true` then just marks it for reindex to process it when everything is done.

Same goes for `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::applyAllRulesOnProduct()`

```
    if ($product->getIsMassupdate()) {
        return;
    }
```

It does not apply the catalog rules for each product when in mass update mode.