# Magento 1: pros and cons of disabling the indexing on mass product import

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, import, performance

I've got a custom script that automatically import a lot of products at once.

I've seen here and there that **it is a huge performance improvement to disable indexing when mass importing products.**

My questions are:

- Is that sentence true ?
- What are the pros / cons of disabling the indexing before importing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros:

- it will be faster because it does not index each product at a time.

Cons:

- you won't see your changes real time. You will have to build the indexes manually when you are done.

Simple as that.
I say you should disable it. It's worth it.

Comment: What about using `setIsMassupdate(true)` on the products ? Is there any difference with "setting index to manual / import / setting index to update on save" ?

Comment: I have no idea. I would suggest to disable the automatic indexing to avoid any other issues and questions that might appear. Specially if it's a custom script. I think it's a good trade. Import what you have to import and reindex when you are comfortable with the result.

Comment: no worries, seems like the other you already answered that: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23784/2380

Comment: Forgot about that. :). I still say you should disable it.